# Submit data for multiple controller actions simultaneously without duplicating logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, dry

I want to include the logic from one controller action (*submitting recipes a chef is allowed to cook*) while also adding extra data to submit and validate (*editing a chef's contact information*). How would I accomplish this without duplicating all the logic?

Example controllers/actions:

### ChefsController

#### #recipes_allowed_to_cook

- cooks have long list of recipes, and here we decide 1-5 recipes of their list that they're allowed to cook at our restaurant

### HiringController

#### #recipes_and_contact_info

- Edit/submit recipes via CooksController#recipes_allowed_to_cook logic
  while also adding/editing a chef's contact information
- i.e. On submit, both recipes and contact info will be validted, but
  recipes will be validated using same code as
  CooksController#recipes_allowed_to_cook

The problem is, **#recipes_allowed_to_cook** has many instance variables and two different sections (one for `:get` and another for `:post`). I want to be able to use this logic simultaenously as I'm also submitting the data for a chef's contact info, so if either portion has errors we render the **#recipes_and_contact_info**.

Comment: You can make a Service Class like `lib/controllers/recipes_allowed_computor.rb` and in this `RecipesAllowedComputor` could hold the logic. Then in yout controller's actions, call the Controllers::RecipesAllowedComputor to compute the allowed recipes.

Comment: How would you handle the instance variables, or would you have to return them at the end? Also, for the redirect/render call, would you have to save that as a variable to return as well and then call it afterwards in both controllers?

Comment: Yes usually I build service classes with the `execute` method (which hold the logic) and this `execute` return the class's instance itself, then I can call several methods on this object, like retrieving some attributes and define instance variables in the controller's action (i can post an example if you want)

Comment: That would be wonderful, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Service Class:

```
# lib/controllers_logic/allowed_recipes_computor.rb
class ControllersLogic::AllowedRecipesComputor
  attr_reader :chief, :recipes

  def initialize(chief)
    @chief = chief
  end

  def execute
    @recipes = @chief.recipes.where(some_logic_to_filter_recipes)
    self
  end
end
```

Then in your controllers' actions:

```
def recipes_allowed_to_cook
  @chief = Chief.find(params[:id])
  computor = ControllersLogic::AllowedRecipesComputor.new(@chief).execute
  @recipes = computor.recipes
end
```